# True case statements are executed even if condition is false - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to select a column only if that column exists.

I've tried this check in this way:

```
set @esisteIlCampo = 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM 
        ( 
            SELECT * 
            FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'ventodelnord' 
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'impiegati' 
            AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Email'
        ) AS t 
    ) > 0
```

If gives 1 if the column Email exists and 0 if not.

Then I have this query to make use of it:

```
SELECT
    `i`.`IDImpiegato` AS `ID`,
    `i`.`TelDomicilio` AS `Numero Di Telefono`,
    CONCAT(`i`.`Nome`, ' ', `i`.`Cognome`) AS `Nome Completo`,
    (
        CASE WHEN
        @esisteIlCampo = 1 
        THEN
        (
            SELECT impiegati.Email from impiegati limit 1 
        ) 
        ELSE
        (
           SELECT "Campo Mancante"
        )
        END
    ) as "Email",
    'Impiegati' AS `Tabella di provenienza`
FROM
    `impiegati` `i`;
```

But even if the `@esisteIlCampo` is 0, so the `@esisteIlCampo = 1` evaluates to false, the `SELECT impiegati.Email from impiegati limit 1` query is executed.

How is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  A SQL query has a fixed set of columns.  You cannot vary it depending on whether a column exists (other than by using `*` or dynamic SQL).

Answer (score 1):

Start by using SELECT INTO

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @esisteIlCampo
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'ventodelnord' 
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'impiegati' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Email';
```

Then you can use

```
SELECT @esisteIlCampo;
```

to see the result.

Then you can use it in your second Query.
Of course make sure hat you get an result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick:

```
select i.*,
       (select email  -- NO qualified name on purpose!!!
        from impiegati i2
        where i2.IDImpiegato = i.IDImpiegato
      ) as email
from impiegati i cross join
     (select 'Camp Mancante' as email) x;
```

This uses a scoping trick in the correlated subquery.  If the column does not exist in `impiegati`, then `email` refers to `x.email`.  If the column does exist, it refers to `i2.impiegati` -- and because of the correlation clause, this should come from the same row.